# Laravel 5.2 uploading file Unable to write in directory

Tags: php, laravel-5, dropzone.js

I'm uploading files in my system and it works locally where am using windows and xampp but when hosting where am using an Linux my file is not being uploaded. I'm getting an error that it cannot be written in the 'system' directory which is within the public folder. This is my code:

```
$destinationPath = 'uploadFiles/'.$input['infolder']; // upload path
$extension = Input::file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension(); // getting file extension
$fileName = $input['type'] .'_'.sprintf("%06d",$input['id']) .'_'. date("Y-m-d_H-i-s") . '.' . $extension; // renameing image
$upload_success =  Input::file('file')->move($destinationPath, $fileName); // uploading file to given path
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the error message? It might be due to missing write rights. Set the rights to 777 for the upload directory and the directories below

Comment: yes i think you have permission error on your sever. 
if you're using Linux "chmod -R 0777 folder_name" run this command.

Comment: I've edited your question to make the screenshot of the error show up on screen, instead of needing to be clicked to. But, the question would be improved further if could copy and paste the error information (or at least the most important parts of it) in; that way the question can be searched/indexed more effectively, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it by changing the destination path to an absolute rather than relative address. Try using:

```
$destinationPath = public_path('uploadFiles/'.$input['infolder']);
```

In a more standard case, the notation would be something like:

```
$path = public_path('images/' . $filename);
```

Otherwise, it could be a permissions problem as suggested in the comments.